# Floating a DIV right causes elements to wrap in IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, css-float

I'm having a problem with floating a container to the right in IE7.  Everything looks fine in IE8+, Firefox, Chrome, and Safari but the elements within the container wrap for some reason in IE7.

I've set up a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/aagC9/.  The problem I'm seeing is visible in the IE7 Browser Mode/Document Mode found in IE9 (it's also in IE7 on XP but I figured this would be easier for people to check out).

While it seems like many people have run into similar problems, their solutions haven't worked for me.  I've tried adding `overflow: hidden` and `overflow: visible` to both the container and elements in various combinations. I also tried setting a fixed width on the `.message` container, but that didn't seem to have any effect either.  While I could just use a fixed left margin on `.message`, it doesn't work 100% since the IE7 doesn't support the box-sizing model.

Does anybody know the secret to getting this to work in IE7 with the float?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm still always surprised when people develop for IE6/7.. I thought IE8 was the accepted defacto corporate standard now.

Comment: Depending on the corp. For some folks I know, they have to still code for IE6! Poor chaps....

Comment: I generally code for IE8+ and then take a look at it in IE7. If it's pretty close, I fix the couple of issues. If not I give up. This happens to be one of the only problems in IE7 so I figured I would just fix it :) I don't even look at it in IE6...

Comment: Could the fact that you've set properties for '.chat-window-container' twice be causing a conflict?

Comment: No, you can set properties on a class as many times as you want. Deleting the first one doesn't change anything.

Comment: Also, you have created divs named: <div class='user1 message'> but in your css you style classes named '.user1' and its children as well as '.message' seperately.. very messy code - everything is everywhere it shouldn't be. You are also using apostrophes >'< instead of speech marks >"< to enclose your html class names. (I don't know if that is normal but I haven't seen it before)

Comment: Unfortunately, this has nothing to do with the problem I'm seeing. Apostrophes and speech marks are completely interchangeable.  CSS is a little messy since I use `scss` to generate my `css` and take advantage of `@extend` and scoping to reduce duplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with your reliance on `display:inline-block;` which IE7 *supports*, just not always *correctly*. Actually, [fix for it is pretty gross](http://flipc.blogspot.com/2009/02/damn-ie7-and-inline-block.html). But, [as in this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aagC9/3/), it works.

Comment: Yep, that was it. Just adding `zoom:1; *display: inline;` to my `inline-block` elements fixed it. Thanks!